# Inno setup command line group parameter clarification

Tags: command-line, inno-setup

I'm having trouble correctly using the `/GROUP=""` command line parameter for my installation when called by a parent installation. What exactly should be specified and what is the "base"?

For example, the parent installer determines the full path to where the start menu entries will be. If this path is passed to `/GROUP`, it gives an error about invalid characters; namely, `:`.

I know the parameter supports use of `expand` prefix, but does this mean the parent installer must determine which constant to "expand" rather than simply passing the already determined path?

**UPDATE:**
It seems I was mistaken in thinking I could select the "base" of the menu entries (all users, local). It seems this is done automatically, but perhaps this is a more complete example:
An older Wise installation determines the filesystem path where the menu entries will be installed. It then executes my installation and passes that path using `/GROUP`. This is where my problem arises because `/GROUP` expects only a directory, not a full path.

Comment: That parameter is not for specifying a full path, but only a directory which will be created as a subfolder in the start menu, so there is no place for `:` char. Besides, when you got that error ? Was that at installation time ? I would expect so, because you cannot create a folder like e.g. `C:\PathToStartMenu\C:\MyGroupName`.

Comment: OK, I can understand it's only a program directory, but what's the base? Current user, all users, common, local, etc...

Comment: That base is described at [`{group}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#group) constant as *"This folder is created under the All Users profile unless the user installing the application does not have administrative privileges, in which case it is created in the user's profile."*. Though I don't know the reason why do you want to get that path, for a single subfolder you can determine it by `ExtractFilePath(ExpandConstant('{group}'))` but I could help you with the precise way to get it if you want.

Comment: So, are you asking how to cut off the start menu directory from that path ? I would rethink that, because now you know that you don't need to do that extra step to determine the start menu path. You can simply pass the final sub-folder.

Comment: Thanks for the help; was able to pass only the directory needed as opposed to the whole path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/GROUP="x"` parameter specifies the value for the `{groupname}` constant, eg. it should be of the form `/GROUP="MyApp"`.  It should not contain a path, or at least if it does contain one it should be a very shallow relative path such as `/GROUP="MyCompany\MyApp"`.

If you are passing the parameter from a parent Inno install script and you want the child install to install icons into the same group as the parent then you should use `/GROUP="{groupname}"`.

In all cases, the "root" of the path will automatically be chosen by Inno to be either `{commonprograms}` or `{userprograms}` depending on the `PrivilegesRequired` setting of the install script being run.

Note that if you are running the installer as part of an automatic update to an already-installed application, you should not pass the parameter at all.  Inno will remember the user's previous selection and use this by default; in fact it's strongly recommended to not offer the user a chance to change this during interactive upgrades by setting the following:

```
[Setup]
DisableDirPage=auto
DisableProgramGroupPage=auto
```